# Sort both the category at the same time

Tags: c#

I have a collection of items with different categories.
Example-

```
     dogs - Shepherd, Sheepdog, Lapphund
     birds - owl, parrot goose
     cats - misty , tigger, kitty
```

i have to store these in a map and display the list in ascending order by both the category and the names.
Expected output -

```
   birds -
   owl
   goose
   parrot
   cats - 
   kitty
   misty
   tigger
   dogs -
   Lapphund
   Sheepdog
   Shepherd
```

my code-

```
   class Animal : IComparable{
    private string name;
    public Animal(string name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string Name{
        get{
            return this.name;
        }
        set{
            this.name = value;
        }
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return 1;

    Animal otherAnimal = obj as Animal;
    if (otherAnimal != null) 
        return this.name.CompareTo(otherAnimal.name);
    else
       return 1;
    }
}
```

But i also want to sort the categories, like first it should display bird, then cat and then dog

Comment: Could you please add definition of the `Animal` class to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the categories you can simply use the sorted dictionaries

create -

```
SortedDictionary<string,Animal>  = new SortedDictionary<string,Animal>();
```

Use the Icomparable to sort the list names of the categories

and thats it.